# Setting overflow:hidden on parent hides all content

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to set up a site that has a "carousel" of divs that are all side-by-side (floated left) each with a full-screen width. Using javascript i plan to move different divs into view by moving the "carousel."

My problem is that for some reason when I set overflow:hidden on the div that contains the carousel all the content is hidden. When I inspect with firebug the divs show up in the correct places but none of the content is visible.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="content_window">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div id="p_home" class="pane">
            Home!
        </div>
        <div id="p_about" class="pane">
            About!
        </div>
        <div id="p_services" class="pane">
            Services!
        </div>
        <div id="p_contact" class="pane">
            Contact!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#content_window
{
    position:relative;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#carousel
{
    position:absolute;
    width:400%;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.pane
{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    color:White;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

If I take the overflow:hidden off of #content_window then the content in the panes becomes visible but horizontal scrollbars are added and you can scroll across and see all the panes. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: clear the divs: `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the last one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a div contains nothing except floated or positioned elements, its height becomes 0. *That* is the problem with div#content_window. Try adding a height to that div:

```
#content_window
{
height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This was the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use absolute positioning at all. Just have the content_window clip the viewport for the carousel. See http://jsbin.com/uhubij/edit#html.

The CSS is much simpler:

```
#content_window {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#carousel {
    width:400%;
}

.pane {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

To switch between the panes, add a `margin-left` to `#carousel`. The first pane is at `margin-left: 0%` (default). The second pane is at `margin-left: -100%;`. The third pane is at `margin-left: -200%;`, etc... For example, here is pane 2: http://jsbin.com/uhubij/2/edit#html

The HTML is basically the same (except I added a clearing div for you):

```
<div id="content_window">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div id="p_home" class="pane">
            Home!
        </div>
        <div id="p_about" class="pane">
            About!
        </div>
        <div id="p_services" class="pane">
            Services!
        </div>
        <div id="p_contact" class="pane">
            Contact!
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have the carousel absolutely positioned so that I can adjust the "left" property using javascript. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that without using absolute positioning on carousel I wouldn't be able to adjust the left attribute. Is there maybe another way I can move the carousel horizontally without adjusting left? The pane width is 25% because I set the width of carousel to 400% (there are 4 panes so 25% of 400% is 100%).

Comment: Well you can always put a `margin-left: 50px;` on the outside container. But if you move the carousel 50px to the right, you also have to make adjustment to the width of the viewport. You can't have the viewport be 100% wide *and* have it moved right 50px, or the right-hand-side 50px will be cut off.

Comment: The whole point is for it to be cut off. Each pane is supposed to be the size of the viewport so that only one pane is visible at a time. My plan is to change which pane is visible by shifting the carousel right and left. So any panes that are off the screen, either to the right or the left, need to be hidden. So if the viewport is 1000px wide then each pane would be 1000px wide. If I wanted to show the first pane I would have left:0 on carousel. If I wanted to show the second pane it would be left:-1000, and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, of course, I understand that. You just need to add a `margin-left: N00%` to switch to pane N+1. See the update in my answer. It was your "50 pixels horizontal" that I was confused about.

Comment: Ah, and now I see the confusion, it was mine =). You had "top: 50px", not "left: 50px;". Duh. Anywaay, the update to my answer still shows you how to do that pane switching. If you want the whole thing moved down 50px vertically, just add `margin-top: 50px;` to the ouside `content_window`.